# RootCA and Trusted RootCA

Tags: certificate-authority

I am planning buy a domain name lets called it foobar.net

Home devices will similarly be added to network called foobar.net

I plan to run a certificate authority to issue certificates to these devices.

Can I get a certificate issued by a Trusted Root Certificate so that all the certificate I issued from my CA have a chain of trust up to a Trusted Root CA

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get a certificate issued by a Trusted Root Certificate so that all the certificate I issued from my CA have a chain of trust up to a Trusted Root CA

no, you can't. The certificate you get from public CA won't allow you to sign other certificates. This is controlled by a [Basic Constraints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) certificate extension. `isCA` bit will be set to 0 in your certificate, meaning, it is end entity certificate and it is not allowed to sign other certificates. More details, for example, in my blog post: https://www.pkisolutions.com/basic-constraints-certificate-extension/